# Function in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace function MMfGetPropValChar(propvalue varbinary(518))
RETURNS varchar(255)
as
$$
select 
    (CASE
     WHEN substr(${PROPVALUE}, 1, 3) = '0x00E700' Then CAST(substr(${PROPVALUE}, 9, 510) As Varchar(255))
WHEN substr(${PROPVALUE}, 1, 3) = '0x01E700') Then CAST(substr(${PROPVALUE}, 9, CAST(substr(${PROPVALUE}, 6, 1) as integer)) As Varchar(64))
)
ELSE (select current_timestamp)
End as test
return test;
$$
```

Below is the error I am getting:

> Compilation of SQL UDF failed: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 0 unexpected 'select'. syntax error line 3 at position 1 unexpected 'CASE'. syntax error line 4 at position 45 unexpected 'Then'.

Comment: Hello there, we have an excellent guide on how to parse and use arguments within a function, the way you have used propvalue does not appear correct.

Go to here to learn more: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-overview.html

Comment: Input Parameter is varbinary how to handle the input parameter in select statement as specified in above function

Comment: I am trying to implement the below code in snowflake by creating a function
declare 
@test VarBinary(518)=0x00E70001010800084100470047004200
Select Case
When SubString(@test, 1, 3) = 0x00E700 Then CAST(SubString(@test, 9, 510) As NVarchar(255))
When SubString(@test, 1, 3) = 0x00A700 Then CAST(SubString(@test, 9, 510) As Varchar(510))
When SubString(@test, 1, 3) = 0x01E700 Then CAST(SubString(@test, 9, CAST(SubString(@test, 6, 1) As Int)) As NVarchar(64))
Else Null
End


Can anyone help me in snowflake by creating a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example might help:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MMfGetPropValChar(p1 varbinary)
RETURNS varchar
as
$$
  select 
    CASE
      WHEN substr(p1::varchar, 1, 3) = '0x00E700' 
         then substr(p1::varchar, 9, 510)::varchar
      WHEN substr(p1::varchar, 1, 3) = '0x01E700' 
         then substr(p1::varchar, 9, substr(p1::varchar, 6, 1))::varchar
   ELSE current_timestamp()::varchar
   End as test
$$
;


SELECT MMfGetPropValChar(to_binary(hex_encode('Snowflake'), 'HEX')) as res;

RES
2021-10-05 05:14:52.369 -0700
```

Note: I cast to varchar using the :: notation, just to make the SQL easier to read.